# Dynamically generate scopes in rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, metaprogramming

I'd like to generate scopes dynamically. Let's say I have the following model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    POSSIBLE_SIZES = [:small, :medium, :large]
    scope :small, where(size: :small) 
    scope :medium, where(size: :medium) 
    scope :large, where(size: :large) 
end
```

Can we replace the `scope` calls with something based on the POSSIBLE_SIZES constant? I think I'm violating DRY to repeat them.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you could do

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  [:small, :medium, :large].each do |s|
    scope s, where(size: s) 
  end
end
```

but I personally prefer:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :sized, lambda{|size| where(size: size)}
end
```

Answer (score 5):

you can do a loop

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    POSSIBLE_SIZES = [:small, :medium, :large]
    POSSIBLE_SIZES.each do |size|
        scope size, where(size: size)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

For rails 4+, just updating @bcd 's answer

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  [:small, :medium, :large].each do |s|
    scope s, -> { where(size: s) } 
  end
end
```

or

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :sized, ->(size) { where(size: size) }
end
```