# Scoping with multiple operations over multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

My goal is do a lot of filtering over some ActiveRecords.

My ideal end game is something like this: [SalesForce screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAwes.png).  (Not pictured: field names can be dragged an dropped from offscreen.  I typed "FOOBAR", specified "equals" and clicked okay for the Account Name field.  I then dragged the Type field).

**Desired functionality:** Filter a model based on user input.  The user might specify a number of fields over which to filter along with an operation for each of those fields.  (Maybe a little more complicated -- I would ideally like to query over non-field methods.  EX: Say a User `has_many: pets`.  It would be nice to be able to filter users with more than 3 pets.)

Most of the fields are text, so I would imagine [contains], [does not contain], [starts with], [ends with], and [equals] will be the dominant scopes needed.

Attempts:

- I have looked at "http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/" and "has_scope", but I'm not entirely sure how to implement cleanly.  (Ties into following bullet:)
- [Dynamically generate scopes in rails models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061595/dynamically-generate-scopes-in-rails-models) seems handy, because I'm working with something like `WHITELISTED_OPERATIONS = ["=", "!=", ">", "<", ">=", "<="]`.  However, this answer is a few years old at this point.
- If worse comes to worse, I could implement each of the operations for each of the fields, but that seems inelegant.

I appreciate your time.

Comment: Have you looked at `ransack` ?  https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack provides a lot of flexibility.

Comment: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack_demo is exactly what I'm looking for (the advanced search mode)